# Grafana click table row and appear data in graph bar

Tags: grafana

Ok, I would like to be able to click the row within my table shown below. Then display the data within the bar graph above.

[image]

So by clicking the row with 'AREA2', it would essentially be changing 'AREA1' to 'AREA2'. So how do I make the rows clickable and be able to make the change to be represented within the bar graph? (Suppose there are more than 100 areas) What is the option I am trying to do even called?

Bar Chart Query:

```
select coalesce(group_name) as group_name,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type = 'HEAD_PHONES') as HEAD_PHONES,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type = 'GUITAR') as guitar,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type = 'XBOX') as xbox,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type is null ) as other
from test
where area = 'AREA1' <-- change to update every row click
group by coalesce(group_name);
```

Entire Table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using URL_links available within the tables.
[image]

Add created a query variable, copied the url for my dashboard and assigned passed the call value as a parameter within my URL.
Resource: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/linking/data-link-variables/